# Check running time per line in python

Tags: python, performance, profiling

I've written a Python script, but running it is taking a lot longer than I had anticipated, and I've no obvious candidate for particuklar lines in the script taking up runtime.

Is there anything I can put in my code to check how long its taking to run through each line?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried running python with profiling?

```
python -m cProfile --sort cumulative your_single_thread_script.py &> out.log
```

You can find more details in this question [How can you profile a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/582336/1714410)

You can read more about the profiling utility [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Comment: what about if I had one script calling a bunch of others, how could I check the time for each individual script?

Answer (score 4):

Use a profiler such as [hotshot](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html). It's easy!

1) run your code with the profiles:

```
import hotshot

prof = hotshot.Profile("hotshot_stats.prof")
prof.runcall(my_function)
prof.close()
```

2) Read the resulting file:

```
from hotshot import stats

s = stats.load("hotshot_stats.prof")
s.strip_dirs()
s.sort_stats('time', 'calls')
s.print_stats(20)
```

Answer (score 3):

`timeit` is a standard module since python 2.3 take a look at the documentation for it.